# Решить проблему в CMS BITRIX

Tags: битрикс

Добрый день! Есть некая проблема.

Есть страница карточки товара.

Код такого плана(чистый *PHP*):

```
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
"bitrix:catalog", 
"main-catalog", 
array(
.......
),
false
);?>
?
```

Мне необходимо вставить три кнопки, при нажатии на которую появляется всплывающая форма. Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, на такой вопрос нельзя дать ответ вида "вот так". Вам необходимо в шаблоне компонента добавить кнопки, нажатие на которые будет отлавливать javascript.

Непосредственно настройками битрикса такой функционал не сделаешь.